# Android Play Services Login: Google Plus cancel button is not working properly

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I am trying to implement `Google+` authentication in my `Android` application. In order to do this, I have followed [this Google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in).

When the permission dialog appears, if the user clicks **SIGN IN**, everything works fine. However, if he clicks **CANCEL**, the dialog closes for a couple of seconds and then shows back up. This goes on forever so there's no way to properly cancel the operation. Why is this happening?

This is the relevant code, adapted from the tutorial:

```
/* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

/* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
/* Track whether the sign-in button has been clicked so that we know to resolve
* all issues preventing sign-in without waiting.
*/
private boolean mSignInClicked;

/* Store the connection result from onConnectionFailed callbacks so that we can
 * resolve them when the user clicks sign-in.
 */
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

/* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
 * us from starting further intents.
 */
private boolean mIntentInProgress;

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/* A helper method to resolve the current ConnectionResult error. */
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
            // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
        // 'sign-in'.
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
}

// Login by email button click listener.
public class ButtonLoginGPlusClicked implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button
                && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // Save credentials.
    Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

    SharedPreferencesHelper.updateStringValue(
            LoginAsVerifiedTracker.this,
            R.string.preferences_user_id,
            currentPerson.getId());
    SharedPreferencesHelper.updateStringValue(
            LoginAsVerifiedTracker.this,
            R.string.preferences_user_name,
            currentPerson.getDisplayName());

    // Close.
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    finish();
    return;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here the onActivityResult class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_SIGN_IN: {
            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }

            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_to_left_enter,
                    R.anim.slide_right_to_left_exit);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the dialog I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: So where's your `onActivityResult` method?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [step 5 of the Google+ Sign In guide](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#add_the_google_sign-in_button_to_your_app):

> You should then reset the state of the flags when control returns to your `Activity` in `onActivityResult`.
>
> ```
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
>     if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
>       if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
>         mSignInClicked = false;
>       }
>       mIntentInProgress = false;
>       if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
>         mGoogleApiClient.connect();
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ```

Note the check against `responseCode` - only when the user has hit the sign in button is `responseCode` equal to `RESULT_OK`. This ensures that the cancel button stops the `resolveSignInError()` call in `onConnectionFailed()` (which is what causes it to loop forever).

Comment: hi can you provide some help for login with google plus sign in one activity and sign out in another activity how to handle when user is logged in am saved loginstatus based on that redirect to navigation.